# What is a "function defined on the real line"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

> What is a "function defined on the real line"?

Is it simply a function $f(x)$ where all values of $x$ are defined?

In other words, $x+1$ is such a function, but $\frac1x$ is not since it is not defined for $0$?

Also, I'm to prove that such a function can be written as a sum of both even and odd function. Is this in the form of $f(x) = g(x)+h(x) = (g+h)(x),$ where $g$ is an even function and $h$ is an odd function?

I'm not looking for proof, as I'm to work that out on my own, but am I correct in interpreting the question, or have I missed something?

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: But note that the property of decompose a function in odd and even parts, is a local property, i.e. it only depends on the point $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so it also is valid for any function defined in any subset of the real line.

Comment: I dunno, I find the idea of, say, $\sqrt x$ as being "the sum of an even function and an odd function" to be rather repulsive.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**; "a function defined on the real line" is a function $f(x)$ that is defined for all real values of $x$.